# EF Core 3.1 - how to do filtering based on parameters?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

In EF Core 2.2 I could do the following:

```
var query = _dbContext.BusinessUnits
                      .Include(a => a.Parent)
                      .Include(a => a.Region)
                      .AsNoTracking()
                      .Select(x => new BUViewModel(x));

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dto.Name))
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.Name.ToLower().Contains(dto.Name.ToLower()));
}

if (dto.Level != null)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.Level == dto.Level);
}

if (dto.ParentId != null)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.ParentId == dto.ParentId);
}
```

Now, seems like 3.1 can't translate this to SQL (I assume you can't add `Where` after `Select`).

If I try to add `Select` after the filtering, compiler tells me that he can't convert `IQueryable<BusinessUnit>` to `IQueryable<BuViewModel>`.

If I try to explicitly declare `IQueryable<BuViewModel> query = ...`, I have to write `Select` before `Where` clauses(and it won't work).

What is the best approach here?

Comment: Try to move the Select at the end, EF will then understand your where clauses.

Comment: tried it, won't work because it will be different type from the one that I declared

Comment: Try something like var query = context.BusinessUnits.AsQueryable(); and then you can query again using this Queryable for the select.

Comment: You sure that in 2.2 it was running the query in SQL and not just dumping all data into memory and running it there? I don't see how any LINQ to SQL engine would be able to translate that Select into SQL.

Comment: @Jimbot, that's what I tried

Comment: @Euphoric, sure that it behaved like you described

Comment: If you are fine by filtering the data in-memory, why not write that explicitly? Use AsEnumerable to turn the IQueryable to IEnumerable to fetch everything and run the filtering on that.

Comment: @Euphoric It wasn't. Just it uses client evaluation, which now has been removed in 3.x. And what you are suggesting is one of the expected ways to resolve it in 3.x.

Comment: @IvanStoev didn't client-side evaluation just dump all data into memory and try to process it via linq-to-objects when it couldn't translate statement into sql?

Comment: @Jamil Indeed. And doing that implicitly. so many users like OP don't even realize that fact. That's why it has been remove and now the users are expected to resolve it one or another way. I personally prefer trying to find and use  translatable construct, and use `AsEnumerable()` only if that's not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem starts with this line. IQueryable constructs an SQL query so this:

```
   .Select(x => new BUViewModel(x))
```

Iqueryable can't call constructors. So to fix that do it manually.

```
.Select(x=> new BUViewModel(){
               Id = x.Id,
               Name = x.Name // etc

            })
```

But why is the constructor not working? Because you can write whatever code you wish in the constructor. EF won't be able to translate to it SQL Query. Let's say you can write a constructor like this.

```
public BUViewModel(int id){
    var apiToken = _serviceCallApi(id);
}
```

The above for example calls an api when it constructs the object (it's just an example). It's impossible to translate this logic to a query. There are tools like automapper which can automatically map the entities.

My guess is simply you weren't dealing with an IQueryable but with IEnumerable. Which is incorrect because you want the SQL to filter the data for you. Not to load everything in memory.